# CSS Style not being applied completely

Tags: html, css, iframe, margin, crop

I am trying to crop the right side of the embedded website within the iframe with `right    : -80px;`. Everything seems to work but the cropping of the right side.

```
<html lang="en">
<body>

<style>
 #div-id{
    border   : 2px solid blue;
    width    : 600px;
    height   : 800px;
    position : relative;
    overflow : hidden;
}
 #iframe-id{
    position : absolute;
    top      : -160px;
    right    : -80px;
    left     : -25px;
    width    : 620px;
    height   : 450vh;
}
</style>
<div id="div-id">
 <iframe title="example" src="https://example.org" id="iframe-id" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I've tried to:

- change the `right` and `left` to `margin-right` and `margin-left`
- "Full"-refreshed the browser via ctrl+F5
- Changed the value from -80px to many different things to see if it is working at all
- Used Edge and Firefox for testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take away the right because you want to go left.

```
<style>
  * {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }

  body,html {
    overflow:hidden;
  }
 #div-id{
    border: 2px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
    width: 40%;
    height: 85%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

 #iframe-id{
    position: absolute;
    top: -160px;
    left: -80px;
    width: 620px;
    height: 450vh;
}
</style>
<div id="div-id">
 <iframe title="example" src="https://example.org" id="iframe-id" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I seem to have misunderstood the purpose then. Nonetheless I now got the positioning right with adjusting the frame itself and minor adjustments on the left/right parameter. Thanks for your answer!